# Neural Network example in .NET

Tags: .net, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Any good tutorial with source that will demonstrate how to develop neural network (step bay step for dummies ;-))

Comment: It's constructive if you want to construct a neural network, and don't know how. The guy who closed it is the one who isn't very constructive ;-)

Comment: I created a neural network library in C# here https://github.com/garrypas/sodiumplus for anyone who is interested

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is good example:
[Brainnet 1 - A Neural Netwok Project - With Illustration And Code - Learn Neural Network Programming Step By Step And Develop a Simple Handwriting Detection System](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/neuralnetwork.aspx) that will demonstrate some practical uses of neural network programming.

Comment: You can read it from my blog as well - http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2008/01/neural-networks-part-i-simple.html

Answer (score 11):

There's a really good article on CodeProject: [Image Recognition with Neural Networks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BackPropagationNeuralNet.aspx).

Comment: In that article the author activates the nodes in the input layer. From what I've learned (from various sources), you shouldn't do this. The input layer only acts as a data holder for the input patterns. Am I wrong or is the author wrong?

Comment: I don't know but isn't it common with backpropagation?

Comment: @ Dennis: I'm not proficient in NN but it sounds reasonable: Separation of concern applied to NN somewhat.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an online course on C# neural network programming.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/course/intro-neural-nets-cs

Answer (score 1):

An interesting tutorial is available [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/neural_dot_net.aspx). Hopefully it will act as an introduction for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at http://generation5.org/articles.asp?Action=List&Topic=Neural+Networks which contains a lot of articles about various types of neural networks targeting both beginners and advanced fields.

Comment: link is broken.