# a simple neural network

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Neural Network example in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100469/neural-network-example-in-net)

Ok this may be a long shot but I was wondering if any one could post a simple neural network and explain how each part works?

The math to these are mind boggling, for some reason because of the math I cant see how I can use it, seems too complex. I understand how they work so to speak but its crazy on the maths.

You dont have to write code maybe some pseudo code and explanations to solve a specific task that you have set to explain your example.

Comment: There is a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100469/neural-network-example-in-net).

Comment: Explain neural networks is a little overly broad.  It would be more appropriate to find a simple example that you didn't understand and post specific questions about it.